# Is every complex bundle a complexification?

Tags: vector-bundles

My question is

> Is a complex bundle $E$ complexification of some real bundle $F$?

My answer

> If and only the transition maps $E_{ij}$ are real

The only if part follows from the fact that transition maps of $F \otimes \Bbb C$ are $F_{ij} \otimes 1$ which are real.

Now suppose that $E_{ij}$ are real. Construct (*the*) real bundle $F$ of rank = rank($E$) with transition maps $E_{ij}$. Complexify it to get $F \otimes \Bbb C$ which is a complex bundle of rank = rank($E$). Then can’t I say that $E$ and $F \otimes \Bbb C$ are same using the uniqueness part of vector bundle construction theorem since both are complex bundles with same rank and same transition maps?

Edit:

I understand that it doesn’t make sense to talk about *the* transition maps. But I guess the condition can be as

> if and if only trivialisations can be chosen such $E_{ij}$ are real

?

Comment: What do you mean by **the** transition maps? If you mean that for **all** choices of trivialization the transition maps are real, then your claim is false. It is true if you say **some.** The right answer is in terms of (principal) frame bundles and existence of a reduction from the complex to the real structure group. But, I have to say, your question is unclear: the title asks for one thing and the body for another.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So can I say, if and only if there exists real transition maps? Or if and only if trivialisations can be chosen such that transition maps are real?

Comment: Right, this is what a reduction means.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Can you provide material which elaborates your argument regarding frame bundles and reduction?

Comment: OK, but later, when I have time.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make really make sense to talk about realness of "the" transition maps. You can always choose different local trivializations and get different transition maps. Even a globally trivial bundle could be described with non-real transition maps.

Anyway, I think the Riemann sphere $S^2$ should give the counterexample you want.

- Every real line bundle on $S^2$ is trivial. This can be seen from the "clutching function" description of vector bundles on spheres.
- That means any complex line bundle on $S^2$ which is the complexification of a real line bundle is also trivial.
- On the other hand, the tangent bundle of $S^2$, viewed as a complex line bundle, is not trivial. That is actually equivalent to the hairy-ball theorem.

Comment: This is the counter example to the statement “Complex bundles are complexification of real bundles”, right? But what about the argument I’ve given? I’ve edited the question.

Comment: I agree that a complex vector bundle is isomorphic to the complexification of a real vector bundle if and only there exists a family of local trivializations for the bundle whose transition maps are real-valued.